# fragment class Exception in GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android

my app crashes every time i run it, i want to find the current location through google api.
the exception i get is  **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycurrentlocation/com.example.mycurrentlocation.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
at com.example.mycurrentlocation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)->setcontentview()**

my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    Location myLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUESTCODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fusedLocationProviderClient= LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        previousLocation();
    }


    private void previousLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUESTCODE);

            return;
        }
            Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location!=null){
                    myLocation=location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myLocation.getLatitude()+""+myLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

                }


            }
        });
        }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng lat = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),myLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(lat).title("Current Loction");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lat));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lat,5));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (REQUESTCODE){
            case REQUESTCODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    previousLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

ManifestFile is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycurrentlocation">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/map_key"
                />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```